# Having an issue uploading a table into Big Query

Tags: file-upload, datatable, google-bigquery

I keep getting an "Failed to create table: Unexpected error" every time I try to upload my CSV file(30,395KB) to Bigquery.

I've tried to see if zipping the file helped but it doesn't.  I've never had this problem before with all of the other CSV files

Comment: Add more details. Screenshots etc, to help yu get this answered

Comment: Uploading large files to cloud storage may help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.